# How to generate a SSL Certificate Signing Request?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, pem, mastercard

I am trying to integrate Master Card facility in my Website. For that I have to make an App first. But in order to make sandbox App it requires **PEM encoded Certificate Request File**.
How can I generate this file? Any sort of help or guide will be appreciated.